# Possibility to link two chapters together to show together in the toc of InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

A friend of mine is writing a student/teacher book. For the teachers the book should have the questions and also the answers in there. But the answer to a corresponding question should be in the second part of the book and not directly after the question. That means, if I have a question on page 10, the corresponding answer could be on page 40.

Is there any possibility to link the question and the answer together to show together in the toc? Should be looking like the following example in the toc:

```
Question 1..........page 10
  Answer 1..........page 40

Question 2..........page 11
  Answer 2..........page 41

Question X..........page X
  Answer X..........page X
```

Hope I could describe my issue understandable, because english is not my native tongue and because of that not very good.

Comment: Related: [InDesign: Table of contents grouped by article type](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/7984/4003)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this could be done automatically. I would generate the TOC so you would have the following

> Question 1..........page 10
>   Question 2..........page 11
>   Answer 1..........page 40
>   Answer 2..........page 41

etc. and then take the entire thing into Excel and sort it by page number. Paste that back into InDesign and style as needed.

Comment: Or sort it by word #2 ascending, word #1 descending: this would give you (Q 1, A 1, Q 2, A 2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the TOC follows the order of your stories. So, I guess that the only way you have to achieve that is by creating a TOC for each question.

You can create multiple TOCs into a single document with TOC Styles. If you need to be guided to do so, I recently wrote a [step-by-step tutorial](https://redokun.com/blog/indesign-table-of-contents).